# Transpose rows to columns and corresponding values BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table

```
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT '2020-12-01 00:00:06 UTC' datetime, 'FuelRate' type, 'l/h' unit, 30.1 Value, 24.1998842 lat,  40.3261354 lon UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-12-01 00:00:06 UTC', 'EngineSpeed', 'rpm', 1850,  24.1998842, 40.3261354  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-12-01 00:00:06 UTC', 'OutdoorTemp', 'C', -1.0, 24.1998842, 40.3261354  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-12-01 00:00:06 UTC', 'FuelLevel', 'L', 78.4, 24.1998842, 40.3261354  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-12-01 00:00:06 UTC', 'HRSengineHours', 'h', 1560, 24.1998842, 40.3261354 
) 

select * from table1
```

which currently looks like this:

[image]

but the desired output would look like this:

[image]

This is my query:

```
SELECT *,
 IF(type = 'FuelRate', val, NULL) AS FuelRate_l_h,
 IF(type = 'EngineSpeed', val, NULL) AS EngineSpeed_rpm,
 IF(type = 'OutdoorTemp', val, NULL) AS OutdoorTemp_C,
 IF(type = 'FuelLevel', val, NULL) AS FuelLevel_L,
 IF(type = 'HRSengineHours', val, NULL) AS HRSengineHours_h,
 
FROM table1, 
UNNEST(['Value']) col,
UNNEST([CASE col
  WHEN 'Value' THEN Value
  END]) val 
  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

But the result looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is in the last part of query:

```
  WITH table1 AS (
      SELECT '2020-12-01 00:00:06 UTC' datetime, 'FuelRate' type, 'l/h' unit, 30.1 Value, 24.1998842 lat,  40.3261354 lon UNION ALL
      SELECT '2020-12-01 00:00:06 UTC', 'EngineSpeed', 'rpm', 1850,  24.1998842, 40.3261354  UNION ALL
      SELECT '2020-12-01 00:00:06 UTC', 'OutdoorTemp', 'C', -1.0, 24.1998842, 40.3261354  UNION ALL
      SELECT '2020-12-01 00:00:06 UTC', 'FuelLevel', 'L', 78.4, 24.1998842, 40.3261354  UNION ALL
      SELECT '2020-12-01 00:00:06 UTC', 'HRSengineHours', 'h', 1560, 24.1998842, 40.3261354 
    ) 
    
    , table2 as (SELECT *,
     IF(type = 'FuelRate', val, NULL) AS FuelRate_l_h,
     IF(type = 'EngineSpeed', val, NULL) AS EngineSpeed_rpm,
     IF(type = 'OutdoorTemp', val, NULL) AS OutdoorTemp_C,
     IF(type = 'FuelLevel', val, NULL) AS FuelLevel_L,
     IF(type = 'HRSengineHours', val, NULL) AS HRSengineHours_h,
     
    FROM table1, 
    UNNEST(['Value']) col,
    UNNEST([CASE col
      WHEN 'Value' THEN Value
      END]) val 
      GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
      
    select datetime, lat, lon, 
    ARRAY_AGG(FuelRate_l_h IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] FuelRate_l_h,
    ARRAY_AGG(EngineSpeed_rpm IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] EngineSpeed_rpm,
    ARRAY_AGG(OutdoorTemp_C IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] OutdoorTemp_C,
    ARRAY_AGG(FuelLevel_L IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] FuelLevel_L,
    ARRAY_AGG(HRSengineHours_h IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] HRSengineHours_h
    from table2
    group by 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
execute immediate (select 'select datetime, ' || string_agg(
  'max(if(type="' || type || '",value,null)) ' || type || '_' || replace(unit,'/','_'),', '
) || ', lat, lon from table1 group by datetime, lat, lon '
from (select distinct type, '_' || replace(unit, '/', '_') as unit from table1)
);
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]